# How to 'print' python output 'live' to Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

i wrote a little flask app which takes some informations via a webform and
when clicking the submit button it perfoms some tasks on a network device.
After this is finished, it shows the results of the tasks.

Every task has it's own function.

ATM all the user sees is some kind of a loading .gif file while the tasks are performed.

This is okay, but it would be great if the output of every function could be shown 'live' on the webpage. Of course, printing to console works but how can i achive to get this output to my html in flask?

let's assume the fuctions which are performed on the device are:

```
ping() -> returns True/False
```

```
connection_to_device() -> returns True/False (and error if error occurs)
```

```
get_info() (returns a string, but it takes some waiting time since the info does not show up instantly)
```

would be great if one could guide me to the right direction.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand there are 2 solution I can think of.

1. Instead of submitting the form, you can use ajax calls and call each individual method which you are invoking on the server, this way you will know exactly what state  your app is in. But this may not be possible if some of the function you have mentioned can only be invoked on the server side. Another thought is that, if you need to show the output from the functions I assume that it takes some time to execute, then at the worst case you can at least isolate and issue a separate call for the function that takes a long time to execute.
2. You can use a **Web socket** so that you will have a continuous feed from the server. Explaining how to do it is for another question of course.

Answer (score -2):

you can do this by simple linux commends, if you have windows then use wsl